# Where does jquery clone render it's content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

Where does jquery clone object that is not appended to anything render it's content? It's not in the page DOM

Say I have this markup:

```
<div class="output">
    <span class="label">hello world</span>
</div>
```

and run this script:

```
var cloned = $('.output').clone();
cloned.find('.label').html('<img src="x" onerror="alert(1);"/>');
```

Why does the alert run despite cloned jquery object not being appended anywhere?

Image isn't rendered anywhere so why is the image loading and onerror firing?

http://jsbin.com/xulilewogi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does alert run?

`img` `src` `"x"` is not found

---

Edit, Updated

> I was asking why cloned element is loading image when it is not
>   rendered anywhere on the page DOM
>
> Why does the alert run
>   despite cloned jquery object not being appended anywhere?

That does not matter with `<img>` elements. For example, try

```
var img = document.createElement("img"); 
img.onerror = function() {alert(1)};
img.src = "x";
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eue0y6ny/

Note, the image is not appended to `DOM`, though request is made for resource set at `src`, and `img.onerror` is called.

Similarly, at `.html('<img src="x" onerror="alert(1);"/>')`, an `<img>` element is created with `onerror` event attribute attached. `<img>` `src` is requested, `onerror` is invoked when resource is not found.

---

See [The `img` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) at

> When the user agent is to **update the image data** of an img element, it
>   must run the following steps:
>
> 10. ⌛ If selected source is null, then set the element to the broken state, queue a task to fire a simple event named `error` at the `img` element, and abort these steps.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. I was asking why cloned element is loading image when it is not rendered anywhere on the page DOM

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How does alert(1) gets converted to function() {alert(1)}? Is that just how onerror behaves?

Comment: Also, what is the reason for this behavior? To allow preloading of images before being actually appended to the DOM?

Comment: @timeiscoffee _"How does alert(1) gets converted to function() {alert(1)}?"_   `alert` is a global function; e.g., try `console.log(typeof alert)`. _"Also, what is the reason for this behavior?"_  The `<img>` does not have to be appended to `DOM`.